# Easiest way to assign text content element to XmlNode[] 'Any' property from bound class?

Tags: c#, xml

Given this:

```
class foo 
{
    public XmlNode[] Any { get;set;}
}
```

What's the easiest way to do this:

```
foo f = new foo();
f.Any  = "some text content";
```

The above sample is an simplification, the actual class is a bound class generated by XSD.exe with an `xs:any` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
foo f = new foo();
f.Any  = new XmlNode[] 
            { 
                new XmlDocument().CreateTextNode("some text content")
            };
```

This seems to be the simplest method I can find.

Answer (score 0):

`Any` is an array of `XmlNode` so clearly you cannot assign a string to it.

you could assign a new array and then you can put XmlNode instances inside by index.

if I had to do something similar I would have a collection instead of an array and I would initialize the collection in the Foo's constructor.

Comment: You can actually assign text to an xs:any,  but iwhen bound via xsd.exe it's created as a XmlNode array which must be filled with a single element of XmlText containing the text content, yet XmlText has no public constructor and it seems it's only possible to create via an instance method on XmlDocument!